# AutocompleteTextView is Not Editable After Navigate Back to prevoius activity with Using Intent flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

Tags: android-intent, android-widget, android-tabhost, autocompletetextview, intentfilter

I have a Tab Activity with 5 Tabs. Each Tab has multiple activities. when i navigate back to previous activity finishFromChild(Activity child) function called where i used Intent flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP.

My Problem created after back to previous activity since my previous activity is a Map activity with Autocomplete Text View after back autocomplete Text View become non editable and keyboard is not showing after click in this Autocomplete textview until i select its text after long press.

Please help me Thanks in Advance

```
**here is my  code for finishFromChild(Activity child)**
@Override
public void finishFromChild(Activity child) {
 LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
  int index = mIdList.size()-1;
  Log.d("in finish from child<>>>>>>>>>>>>>", ""+index+"");
  if (index < 1) {
      finish();
      return;
  }

  manager.destroyActivity(mIdList.get(index), true);
  mIdList.remove(index); index--;
  String lastId = mIdList.get(index);
  Intent lastIntent = manager.getActivity(lastId).getIntent();
  Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(lastId, lastIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP));
  setContentView(newWindow.getDecorView());
```

}

```
**and Here is my Code for AutocompleteTextView**
try {
        TenLifeDataSource dataSource = new TenLifeDataSource(this);
        mSearchedCitymList = dataSource.getAllCityBySearchString();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    findViewById(R.id.headerLogoImageView).setOnClickListener(
            new InfoButtonListener(this));

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, mSearchedCitymList);
    Log.d("check it", "i m in editor");
    mSearchAutoCompleteText = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.searchBox);
    mSearchAutoCompleteText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
    // mSearchEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(mEditorActionListener);
    mSearchAutoCompleteText
            .setOnEditorActionListener(mEditorActionListener);

    mSearchAutoCompleteText.setAdapter(adapter);
    mSearchAutoCompleteText
            .setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {

                    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext()
                            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    inputManager.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);
                    mSearchAutoCompleteText.dismissDropDown();

                    /*
                     * if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(v.getText())) {
                     * mLastSearchedString = v.getText().toString();
                     * showSearchResults(); //return true; }
                     */
                    mLastSearchedString = mSearchAutoCompleteText.getText()
                            .toString();
                    // //Log.d("test adderess here", mLastSearchedString);
                    // mLastSearchedString = v.getText().toString();
                    if (mLastSearchedString.length() > 0) {
                        // Log.d("center",
                        // ""+mLastSearchedString.length()+"");
                        getlocationinfo(mLastSearchedString);
                    }

                    // if(menuItems.size() <= 0)
                    // showSearchResults(mLastSearchedType);
                    // updateSuppliers(mLastSearchedType);

                    // showSearchResults();

                }
            });
```

Comment: Instead of using this in  i.e. this.findViewById(R.id.searchBox); use getParent().findViewById(R.id.searchBox); replace all "this" by "getParent()"  It may be works in your case.!!